Telegram bot sends a 16:9 video in the shape of a square
Video download code:
async def download_video(url, size):
    ydl_opts = {
        'outtmpl': 'video.mp4',
        'format': f'bestvideo[height={size}][ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best',
        'merge_output_format': 'mp4',  
        'noplaylist': True
    }
    try:
        with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)

Video sending code:
await bot.send_video(video=FSInputFile("video.mp4"), chat_id=chat_id)

Example of link and quality: https://vk.com/video-220754053_456241914 / 1080p
This problem occurs when sending high-quality videos.
An example of how a video arrives:
An example of how a video arrives
If the video is saved to the gallery, it is displayed normally.
I tried to put 1 frame of video as a preview. I also tried to change the metadata and specify the 16:9 format specifically — none of this helped solve the problem.
